# which one is executed first

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web application in php, I don't know which one will be ever called an processed first,

In my php file, I also have a javascript code

`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){});
</script>`

In my php code, I will send an array object into that javascript. So I wonder why the php code is executed first instead of the javascript ? Does it mean that all server code will always be executed before the client script runs during the browser view is shown.

Comment: your PHP is executed on the server, and the output sent to the client. The client then executes your javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, normally, the whole server processing finished before the page is delivered to the browser. At this moment, JavaScript execution starts.

You can add late execution of PHP code using AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

The server side code is executed first and the output generated by server side is sent back to client where client side code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the server code (be it PHP,ASP,JSP,etc) runs first in the server, it generates an html page which contains your javascript code, your computer receives this page, renders it in the browser and runs the javascript in it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have html,php,js in a single file you should know these two things   only:

1)your file extension must be .php (because php execution required .php extension)

2)you will see the output exactly in the same order as you typed in your file.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
 echo "i m php upper"."</br>";
?>
<p id="pg">i am html upper</br></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(" i am javascript upper</br>");
</script>
<?php
 echo "i m php bottem"."</br>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(" i am javascript bottom</br>");
</script>
<p id="pg">i am html bottem</br></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**...output looks like this...**

i m php upper

i am html upper

i am javascript upper

i m php bottem

i am javascript bottom

i am html bottem